# pino logger configuration that works on server as well as on the browser

Tags: logging, pinojs, pino

Can the same logger be used for the browser and server.  Here is the configuration for the logger. When I log on the server of an express application it does not log anything, it logs on the browser however. Do I need to separate the browser and server logger configurations or should this work? If so, what I'm am doing wrong?

```
            const logger = pino({
               browser: {
                  asObject: true,
                  serialize: true
               },
                  level: 'info',
                  name: 'app',
                  levels: levels,
                 transport: {
                  target: 'pino-pretty',
                  options: {
                    colorize: true,
                    minimumLevel: 'info',
                    timestampKey: 'time',
                    levelFirst: true,
                    ignore: 'pid,hostname',
                    levels: levels,
               }
           },
              serializers: {
              req: pino.stdSerializers.req,
              res: pino.stdSerializers.res
        }
    })
```